# Arguments to require'd function get lost/disappear in Lua?

Tags: lua

While I don't really know Lua, this is a rather unexpected and bizarre behavior.

Let's say I have `my_module.lua`:

```lua
local function dump(o) -- SO:9168058
  if type(o) == 'table' then
    local s = '{ '
    for k,v in pairs(o) do
       if type(k) ~= 'number' then k = '"'..k..'"' end
       s = s .. '['..k..'] = ' .. dump(v) .. ','
    end
    return s .. '} '
  else
    return tostring(o)
  end
end


local mymodule = {}

function mymodule.myfunction(indict)
  print(dump(indict))
end

return mymodule
```

Ok, now I run this:

```
lua5.3 -e "mm=require('my_module'); mm:myfunction({aa=12})"
```

This should not be complicated - I "import" the module, and call a function in it with an argument that is an object (the table/associative array/dictionary `{aa=12}`). Then I simply try to print this argument from within the function. However, I get this:

```
$ lua5.3 -e "mm=require('my_module'); mm:myfunction({aa=12})"
{ ["myfunction"] = function: 0x5619aeddf770,}
```

So, the response to `print(dump(indict))` inside `myfunction`, where `indict` is an argument passed to `myfunction`, Lua prints .... `"myfunction"` ????!

I cannot even wrap my head around this - how can this possibly happen ?

And how can I pass an object as an argument to a function, such that when I print the argument from within the function, the object which is the argument is printed - and not the function itself ??!

Btw, the same happens even if I just pass a number instead of an object, say:

```
lua5.3 -e "mm=require('my_module'); mm:myfunction(42)"
```

---

EDIT: did a bit of debugging - so with this:

```
function mymodule.myfunction(indict)
  print(indict)
  print(dump(indict))
end
```

... I get this printout when using a numeric argument:

```
$ lua5.3 -e "mm=require('my_module'); mm:myfunction(42)"
table: 0x55f15a7a07a0
{ ["myfunction"] = function: 0x55f15a7a07e0,}
```

... so it simply doesn't see this number anywhere, but the function sees itself as the first argument.

This reminded me, how in a Python class, you have to write methods as functions with "self" as first argument, so I tried this:

```
function mymodule.myfunction(self, indict)
  print("self", self, "indict", indict)
  print(dump(indict))
end
```

... which prints:

```
$ lua5.3 -e "mm=require('my_module'); mm:myfunction(42)"
self    table: 0x560510b5a7d0   indict  42
42
```

... or in case of passing an obect:

```
$ lua5.3 -e "mm=require('my_module'); mm:myfunction({aa=12})"
self    table: 0x55d51c9d5800   indict  table: 0x55d51c9d5880
{ ["aa"] = 12,}
```

... well, that's more like it ...

Can anyone explain where does this come from - why do I need to add a "self" argument in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In lua, the call `a:b(x)` passes a reference to the object `a` as the first (`self`) parameter to the function `b`.

Since your module definition is:

```
function mymodule.myfunction(indict)
```

and the call statement is `mm:myfunction`, the object/table `mm` is passed as the first parameter (which here is `indict`).

Either change the function definition to

```
function mymodule:myfunction(indict)
```

if you want to keep call like `mm:myfunction`, or call the function as `mm.myfunction`.

---

The behaviour is discussed in detail in the [PiL book](https://www.lua.org/pil/16.html) on OOP concepts.

> The effect of the colon is to add an extra hidden parameter in a
>   method definition and to add an extra argument in a method call. The
>   colon is only a syntactic facility, although a convenient one; there
>   is nothing really new here.

Comment: Many thanks @hjpotter92 - that's exactly what I was missing, the understanding of what the effect of the colon is: didn't imagine it adds an extra argument.